# Custom Module - Please correct the XML data and try again. [] []

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, adminhtml

I'm building a custom module which needs a grid and edit form for my model. I managed to build the grid from a tutorial and my edit controller works as well.
However, there is no content being rendered and I get this error:

[2017-05-30 10:48:12] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_395a947ddb2d131e0726ca40a8f539941 and handles default, slideshow_slide_edit: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

my layout slideshow_slide_edit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="left">
        <block class="Myvendor\Slideshow\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit\Tabs"
            name="myvendor_slideshow_slide.edit.tabs"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block class="Myvendor\Slideshow\Block\Adminhtml\Slide\Edit" name="myvendor_slideshow_slide.edit"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

The Slide/Edit Block is obviously constructed as some additional buttons appear, and with some die-debugging I was able to confirm the Slide/Edit/Tabs Block is constructed as well, but neither of them have any content. I am not even sure where to look for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a the closing `</page>` tag. probably that caused your XML File to be incorrect, the rest looks fine to me.

also you should change
`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"`
to 
`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"` this is not neccessary but it's recommended to use the relative path

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the `</page>` tag was merely lost in copy paste, it is present in the file. I changed the schema location, but as you expected that makes no difference. I begin to suspect the layoutfile might not be the problem since the constructors of both blocks do get called after all.